# Named Inputs and URLs

Tags: sas

I'm trying to read some log data into SAS Enterprise Guide. The data contains some URLs among other types of variables. The format is not native to SAS, so that's why it might look a bit wired to some of you. I have made an example of the code (the original data contains personal informations) using datalines (in my program I'm using the infile-statment), so you can get an idea of my horrific situation:

```
DATA URL;
    INFILE datalines delimiter=" " dsd EXPANDTABS TRUNCOVER;
    INPUT F1 $18. REQUESTURL=$40. URL=$40. REFERER=$40.;
    DATALINES;
    21-07-2017 REQUESTURL="www.google.dk" URL="www.jubii.dk/user=hej" REFERER="(Iphone CPU Iphone OS)"
    ;
RUN;
```

The results is that the variable URL is missing, which to my knowlegde is a result of the equal sign in the string. SAS reads what comes before the equal sign as a new variable, which is what i'm trying to avoide. I would prefer using named inputs (e.g. REQUESTURL=), because it names the variables. But I need to get the full string of URL, since it contains alot of information (in the original dataset). 
I've tried using PROC IMPORT with a space delimiter, but that divides the variable REFERER.

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions to capture the data you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So looking at the example of values with embedded equal signs in the documentation https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0148147.htm#z0148299 they mention the presence of double spaces around the value.  So I tried pre-processing your dataline to convert the double quote characters into double spaces instead.

```
filename sample temp;
data _null_;
  file sample;
  infile cards expandtabs truncover ;
  input line $200. ;
  line = tranwrd(line,'"','  ');
  len=lengthn(line);
  put line $varying200. len;
cards;
21-07-2017 REQUESTURL="www.google.dk" URL="www.jubii.dk/user=hej" REFERER="(Iphone CPU Iphone OS)"
;
```

Then it worked.

```
DATA URL;
  INFILE sample TRUNCOVER;
  LENGTH F1 $18 REQUESTURL $40 URL $40 REFERER $40;
  INPUT F1  REQUESTURL= URL= REFERER= ;
run;
```

[image]

You might also need to collapse any existing double spaces.

```
line = tranwrd(compbl(line),'"','  ');
```

Comment: Thank you! It even worked without the additional tranwrd function.

Comment: Depends on the values. If you had `referer="abc  xyz"` then you would end up with just `abc` instead of `abc  xyz`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use something akin to named inputs alongside DLM/DSD.  SAS is pretty smart about this sort of thing.  Putting both in lets you use the `"` to capture the whole Referer string.  But I think you want to use the below style of input rather than your style; note the relatively small difference (the `"` around them) which causes SAS to advance the pointer to the text string, and then lets you mix in the DLM/DSD style input.

I saved your example to a text file and get the expected result from the below code.  The `=` inside the URL string should not cause any trouble.

```
data want;
length requestURL url referer $32767;
  infile "c:\temp\testurl.txt" lrecl=32767 pad dsd dlm=' ';
input
  @"REQUESTURL=" requestURL $
  @"URL=" url $
  @"REFERER=" referer $
  ;
run;
```

Comment: Genious! Thank you very much, Joe. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I would read the entire line in and then parse it with the `SCAN()` function.

```
DATA URL;
    INFILE datalines dsd TRUNCOVER;
    format F1 $18. REQUESTURL $40. URL $40. REFERER $40.;

    input;

    F1 = scan(_infile_,1," ");
    REQUESTURL = scan(scan(_infile_,2," ",'q'),2,"=",'q');
    URL = scan(scan(_infile_,3," ",'q'),2,"=",'q'); 
    REFERER = scan(scan(_infile_,4," ",'q'),2,"=",'q');

    DATALINES;
    21-07-2017 REQUESTURL="www.google.dk" URL="www.jubii.dk/user=hej" REFERER="(Iphone CPU Iphone OS)"
    ;

RUN;
```

`SCAN(string,i,<delimiter>,<modifier>)`  Gets the `i`th word from the `string` using the `<delimiter>` and `<modifier>`.

The `'q'` modifier tells `scan()` to ignore spaces inside of quotes.